# eclipse conexão à base de dados

Tags: java, swing

```
btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              try { Connection lig = DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:mysql://localhost/gym", "root", "");
              PreparedStatement inst = lig .prepareStatement(
              "SELECT * FROM contauser WHERE Username=? AND Password=?");
              inst.setString(1, txtUser.getText());
              char[] Password=txtPass.getPassword();
              inst.setString(2, new String(Password)); 
              int linhas = inst.executeUpdate();
              lig.close(); if (linhas == 1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Logged in");
            CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame.getContentPane()
                    .getLayout();
            card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "MenuPrincipal");

              }

              else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
              ("Invalid username or password"));

              } catch (SQLException e1) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
              "Impossível ligar à base de dados");
              System.out.println(e1.getLocalizedMessage());

              }
             }
    });
```

*erro

> Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs

Comment: Ola. Bem vindo ao SOPT. A sua esta muito confusao. Veja [aqui como perguntar ](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Troque `executeUpdate()` por `executeQuery()`. `executeUpdate()` é utilizado para executar um comando do tipo UPDATE, INSERT ou DELETE e não um SELECT.

Comment: Obrigado ramaral, já funciona.

Comment: @ramaral transforme em resposta :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Julgo que, da forma como está feita a pergunta, a minha resposta não irá ajudar mais alguém além do AP. Já há até votos para fechar que deverão ser por essa razão.

Comment: Mas não deixa de ser uma resposta e no caso a certa para o autor. :)